# Redirect non-existing subfolders with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdirectory

I have a site where I have some links like this: http://mysite.com/search-RANDOM_WORDS.htm
The problem is that Google tries to index links like:

```
http://mysite.com/search-RANDOM_WORDS.htm/existing-link-on-the-site
http://mysite.com/search-WORD.htm/link-on-the-site/search-ANOTHER_WORD.htm
```

etc. etc. The site doesn't use subfolders in links, every link is on the root. I don't really understand from where Google is taking these links through, but I have to fix it somehow. I am using mod_rewrite already, but I did not found yet a working solution for my problem. It should work like this:

1. If the link what is trying to access contains a subfolder which doesn't exist on the server
2. reditect it to the root with 404 error.

How can be done this?
Thanks!

Comment: So you want to redirect `http://mysite.com/search-WORD.htm/link-on-the-site/search-ANOTHER_WORD.htm` to `http://mysite.com/search-WORD.htm` ?

Comment: Yes, something like that, or better to keep the last "subfolder": `http://mysite.com/search-WORD.htm/link-on-the-site/search-ANOTHER_WORD.htm` to be: `http://mysite.com/search-ANOTHER_WORD.htm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(search-.+?\.htm)/.*$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: This is not OK, because it falls in redirect cycle if I try to reach a valid link like: `http://mysite.com/search-WORD.htm` The correct will be: `RewriteRule ^(search-.+?\.htm/).*$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC]`